# Cross platform, stable, and with great feature web platform

Tags: c#, java, .net, python, linux

We are a group of 2 C# programmers, which have experience in wcf web services, asp.net MVC 3, different architectural patterns, Inversion of control etc.
We have to implement a web site, which will run on Linux with minimum of 10k online users.
The problem is that it will run on Linux, and we don't know what language to choose, which is stable, maintained, free, cross platform, and reusable in business/desktop applications.
We think about Java servlets and Python's Django framework, are there other good frameworks?
Which one to choose, we are confused.
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT:**
**What about the performance of JSP vs Django vs Asp.net MVC on Mono vs Ruby On Rails?**

Comment: There are a million answers to this floating around the net. Did you look and see if Java servlets or Django meet your needs?

Comment: Yes they meets my need, but which one to choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We are a group of 2 C# programmers, which have experience in *(snip)* asp.net MVC

You want to write a web-site, and you have asp.net MVC experience... ASP.NET MVC *can run on linux / Mono*. So my suggestion... *do that*.

Some links:

- [Deploy ASP.NET MVC on Linux: Best Practices, Tools & Surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172429/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-linux-best-practices-tools-suprises)
- [Developing ASP.NET MVC Apps Using Mono](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/02/developing-asp-net-mvc-apps-using-mono/)
- [Setting up a Ubuntu, Apache, MySQL, Mono, ASP.NET, MVC 2 Development Server](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/6/Setting-up-a-Ubuntu-Apache-MySQL-Mono-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Development-Server)
- [mono FAQ : ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET)

Comment: Of course, we tried mono, but it doesn't have third version of asp.net MVC, and the only serious web site is ifolder, developed by Novell..
I read reviews about it, many says that's is not mature for big projects..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind moving out of your comfort zone, I would recommend Ruby on Rails (on top of Django and JSP).

Comment: Good. Especially when hosted on nginx+passenger (instead of Apache). Once you get the hang of it, you can experiment with multiple ruby implementations (notably v1.8.7, v1.9.2 and JRuby) and see which works best for you, though I'd recommend v1.9.2 (it being the latest standard/reference implementation)

Answer (score 1):

I love Python and Django, and even use it in every projects I have at school/uni before.

But it's just me, who have some experience with Python; everything you know have some real-world sample with large scale, so choose the one you like/know best.

You are going to deploy in Linux, so maybe ASP.NET is a acceptable choice, but not the best. I would recommend Django (because I love it); Ruby on Rails is another good choice, but I don't like it because of some bad experience before with its dependencies. Python and Ruby both has its advantages and dis-advantages.

There's another web development framework choice for Python like Pylons (Quora use it), webpy...